# socket.isConnected returns false

Tags: c#, android, windows, bluetooth

I am writing a pc & phone communication app. The pc code is written in C#. When I connect my phone (which is paired with pc) to my pc, the phone connects however the logs say, the socket is not connected i-e; socket.isConnected() returns false on my phone. I have tried to run this app on multiple phones and the problem persists.

I think the issue is with my C# code as I don't know C# well.

**Following is the c# code:**

```
        BluetoothListener blueListener = new BluetoothListener(mUUID);
        blueListener.Start();


        BluetoothClient conn = blueListener.AcceptBluetoothClient();

        if(conn.Connected)
            updateUI("Mobile connected");


        Stream mStream = conn.GetStream();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] received = new byte[1024];
                mStream.Read(received, 0, received.Length);
                //.....
            }
            catch() {}
        }
```

*I am using 32feet library in C#.*

**Following is my Android code:**

```
BluetoothSocket socket = selectedDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
try
    {
        socket = openSocketForSendingData();

        try
        {
            BluetoothAdapter bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            bAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            socket.connect();

            Log.e("NP socket", "No Exception");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("NP socket Exception", e.toString());
        }


        if(socket == null)
            Log.e("Socket NULL", "socket is null");


        if(!socket.isConnected())
        {
            Log.e("NP socket", "socket not cconnected");

            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Socket CLOSE",e.toString());
            }

        }
        else
            Log.e("NP socket", "socket  cconnected");   

        if(socket.getOutputStream() == null)
            Log.e("Soccket Outupt", "output stream null");  

        dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeChars("Hello World I am android");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("NP writing socket", e.toString());   
    }
```

*The UUID in both codes is same.*

Can you guide me what mistake am I making?

PS: Before asking this question, I have already spent all day searching the solution on internet, but it was no good.

Regards

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?